# LinkedLists and objects in them

Tags: java, object, data-structures, linked-list

I am having trouble using LinkedLists and adding objects to them.

When I add an object to the LinkedList, and try to access the object's methods, I am given the generic object methods.

For example:

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list.add("hey");
    list.getFirst(). // this is the line of code I am referring
```

When I try to get the methods of a String object, I instead get generic      object methods such as: c`lone(), equals(Object obj), finalize(), getClass(),   hashCode()`, etc.

Comment: And what are you planning to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are using the raw type `LinkedList` without a type parameter in angular brackets. Try this

```
LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add("hey");
String string = list.getFirst();
```